# User Data script not downloading files from S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

i have s3cmd and EC2 api  pre configured AMI. While creating new instance with user data for downloading files from S3 bucket, i face some following problems.

in user data i have code for 
- creating new directory on new instance.
- downloading file  from AWS S3 bucket.

Script is

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /home 
mkdir pravin
s3cmd get s3://bucket/usr.sh >> temp.log
```

But in above script , `mkdir pravin` creates new directory with name pravin but `s3cmd get s3://bucket/usr.sh` not downloads file from AWS S3 bucket.

it also creates `temp.log` but it is empty.

So how i can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to use an instance that has an `IAM` role assigned to it and the `aws-cli`, which would require that you have `Python` installed. All of this could be accomplished by inserting the following in the `user-data` field for your instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -y install python-pip
apt-get -y install awscli

mkdir pravin
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/usr.sh temp.log --region {YOUR_BUCKET_REGION}
```

**NOTE: The above is applicable for Ubuntu only.**

And then for your instances `IAM` role you would attach a policy like so:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[{
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketName/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the user running the user data script lacks a `.s3cfg` file. You may need to find a way to indicate the location of the file when running this script.

Comment: Pass the `-c FILE` or `--config=FILE` option to s3cmd pointing to the directory holding `.s3cfg`